# Nonhomogeneous Equations - Method of Undetermined Coefficients

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was sick during our lecture when we went over this. I'm stuck on a difficult review problem, and can't figure out where I'm going astray.

The problem is:
$$y''+4y=t^2+2e^t, y(0)=0, y′(0)=1.$$

This is how I've been solving the problem:
$$r^2+4=0$$
$$r=\pm 2i$$
Since r is complex, convert to Euler's formula:
$$y_c=c_1\cos{2t}+c_2\sin{2t}$$
Now, to find $y_p$ (which I break into $y_{p1}$ and $y_{p2}$:
$$y_{p1}=At^2+Bt+C$$
$$4At^2+2A+4Bt+4C=t^2$$
$$A=1/4, B=0, C=-1/8$$
$$y_{p2}=De^t$$
$$De^t+4De^t=2e^t$$
$$D=2/5$$
Then, plugging that into y:
$$y=y_c+y_{p1}+y_{p2}$$
$$y=c_1\cos{2t}+c_2\sin{2t}+\frac{1}{4}t^2-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{2}{5}e^t$$
Find y':
$$y'=-2c_1\sin{2t}+2c_2\cos{2t}+\frac{1}{2}t+\frac{2}{5}e^t$$
Solve for $c_1,c_2$
$$c_1=-\frac{11}{45}$$
$$c_2=\frac{3}{10}$$

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, I'm just following a similar problem from our ebook (which unfortunately I can't share), but they also break $y_p$ into two parts to make it easier. I also don't know the real answer, as the program we use won't show me it...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your $c_1$ is wrong. It should be $-11/40$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were so close
$$y(0) = c_1+\frac{11}{40} = 0$$
$$y'(0) = 2c_2 + \frac{2}{5} = 1$$

Solving gives $c_1 = -11/40$, $c_2 = 3/10$